# Facing issue with Internal stage data created using Parquet File Format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file in parquet format with 10 columns where in few columns are nullable. I had created a fileformat with type as parquet and Null_if set to ''. When i copy the files to the internal stage, for few records i see the columns which are having null values are missing in the record. Can anyone help me out with the resolution of having all the columns in the record.

My Data in file:
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
'A'  Null 'B'  'D'

Data reflecting in the internal stage:

{
Col1 : "A",
Col3 : "B",
Col4  : "D"
}

Comment: can you provide the full file_format statement?

Comment: create or replace file format test_parquet type='parquet', NULL_IF='', Compression='Auto',TRIM_SPACE=false,BINARY_AS_TEXT=true;